# Preserving box plot whiskers when mixing box and violin plots in {ggplot2}

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Preamble

Let's say I have a function that allows users to create a boxviolin plot where box and violin plots are superposed.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- dplyr::filter(mpg, class %in% c("compact", "midsize"))

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_violin() + geom_boxplot() 

p1
```

[image]

I also want to allow users to remove the violin plot if they want to and the way I support this is by asking users to set the width of the violin plot to `0`.

```r
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_violin(width = 0) + geom_boxplot() 

p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Problem

If you notice carefully, the box plot whiskers between the two plots have changed. I think this is because the violin plot increases the range of data by interpolating data, which makes the outlier points no longer outliers.

How can I avoid this? That is, how can I allow users to make the violin plot disappear without affecting the boxplot whiskers?

N.B. I am aware that I can just offer a parameter like `plot.type` and then add the violin layer based on its argument. But this is not the API I prefer for other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the box plot whiskers which change. When you set `width=0` the violin collapses to a flat line. To avoid that or to remove it completely set `linewidth=0` too:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- dplyr::filter(mpg, class %in% c("compact", "midsize"))

ggplot(df, aes(class, hwy)) +
  geom_violin(width = 0, linewidth = 0) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use color and fill parameters as NA instead to make any plot invisible.

```
  df <- dplyr::filter(mpg, class %in% c("compact", "midsize"))
  
  p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_violin() + geom_boxplot() 
  
  p1
  
  p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_violin(color=NA,fill=NA) + geom_boxplot() 
  
  p2
```

[image: Like this]